How to execute remote PS script independently
Let imagine there is a PowerShell script already there in a remote computer and let that script composed of 8 lines. When I try to run that script from my local computer by using “Invoke-Command”, all execution were display in my local computer’s PowerShell ISE console from start to end. Let, due to any reason if it halt at line number 4, it did not continue to execute remaining lines independently to the end in that remote computer. How can I run that independently non-interactively without showing each line output in local computer PowerShell ISE console ? Because the results are returned to my local computer.
How can I run that independently non-interactively without showing each line output in local computer PowerShell ISE console ? Because the results are returned to my local computer.

You could invoke Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-File path\to\script.ps1' in the remote session

You mean like this ?
Invoke-Command -Session $ssn {
Invoke-Expression -Command "C:\temp\reip.ps1"
Start-Process -FilePath "PowerShell.exe" -ArgumentList "%SystemDrive%\temp\reip.ps1"
}
